# Capturing version numbers using regex python

Tags: python, regex

Using a rest api I get the following forms of strings back:

```
/primerjs-0.0.3-3.tgz
/primerjs-0.0.3.tgz
/0.0.3-16
```

I want to grab just the 0.0.3 part from the above strings.  I came up with the following regex expression:

```
(\d+\.)+\d*(?!tgz)
```

and I have tested it on an online regex tester and it seems to grab what I want it to.  However the following code only prints ['0.']

```
text = '/primerjs-0.0.9.tgz'
m = re.findall(r"(\d+\.)+\d*(?!tgz)", text)
print m
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a non-capturing group:

```
(?:\d+\.)+\d*(?!tgz)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJeMD2/2)

Or, use an alternative pattern:

```
[/-](\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJeMD2/1)

Both will work well with [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) with your examples. The first one has no capturing groups, so `re.findall` will output match values, and the second will output only captured values (Group 1 contents) since `re.findall` returns capture group contents if capturing groups are defined inside the pattern.

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/zGHkRV):

```
import re
rx = r'[/-](\d+\.\d+\.\d+)'
print(re.findall(rx, '/primerjs-0.0.3-3.tgz   /primerjs-0.0.3.tgz   /0.0.3-16'))
rx = r'(?:\d+\.)+\d*(?!tgz)'
print(re.findall(rx, '/primerjs-0.0.3-3.tgz   /primerjs-0.0.3.tgz   /0.0.3-16'))
```

Output:

```
['0.0.3', '0.0.3', '0.0.3']
['0.0.3', '0.0.3', '0.0.3']
```

Answer (score 1):

using parenthesis create object groups. here I selected the `0` group that means *give me the whole match*

the code:

```
text = '/primerjs-0.0.9.tgz'
...: m = [x.group(0) for x in re.finditer(r"(\d+\.)+\d*(?!tgz)", text)]
...: print m[0]
'0.0.9'
```

a better approach is to use search instead of `re.findall()`

```
text = '/primerjs-0.0.9.tgz'
   ...: m = re.search(r"(\d+\.)+\d*(?!tgz)", text).group(0)
   ...: print m
'0.0.9'
```

you can even add named group for clarity:

```
text = '/primerjs-0.0.9.tgz'
...: m = re.search(r"(?P<version>(\d+\.)+\d*(?!tgz))", text).group('version')
...: print m
'0.0.9'
```